# Best practices for huge volumes of data load/unload?

Tags: database, oracle, design-patterns, architecture

My question applies to ETL scenarios, where transformation is performed outside of database (completely). 
If you were to Extract, Transform, and Load huge volumes of data (20+ million records or more) and the databases involved are : Oracle and MSSQL Server, what would be the best way to:

1. Effectively read from the source database : Is there a way I could avoid all the querying over the network? I have heard good things about Direct Path Extract method/ bulk unload method - I'm quite not sure how they work, but I presume I would need a dump file of sorts for any kind of non-network based data read/import?
2. Effectively write the transformed
   data to the target database?: Should
   I consider Apache Hadoop? Will it
   help me start my transformation and
   parallely load all my data to the
   destination database? - Would it be
   faster than say, Oracle's bulk load
   utility? If not,, is there a way to
   remote invoke bulk load utlities on
   Oracle/MSSQL Server?

Appreciate your thoughts/suggestions.

Comment: What is the size of the data in gigabytes?

Comment: Are you always using the same database for the source and the target?  That is, are you always going from Oracle to SQL Server or vice versa?  Can you build database specific extract and load code?  Or are you trying to build an ETL process that is database agnostic?

Comment: @jonearles Unfortunately, I do not have size information. However, let's presume its huge enough that it would take more than an hour to transfer it over a network link.

Comment: @Justin Not necessarily always - But most of the time, I could be using the same database for source and target. Very rarely would I do an ETL from Oracle to SQL Server or vice versa. Currently, extract and load happens outside of db environments via jdbc, so yea, the ETL process is database agnostic so far. But, I wouldn't mind exploring methods that would improve performance greatly during extract/load, even if I were to write db-specific code. At this point, my product only supports 3 databases - Oracle, MSSQL and Sybase.

Answer (score 1):

I would always use the db's bulk load facilities for this. Remote control of bulk loads is a sysadmin issue; there is always a way to do this.

This means that the first two stages of ETL would be and application that generates the right file format for the bulk load facility, and the last stage would be to invoke bulk loading.

Answer (score 0):

If you extract the data to a flat file, you can use Oracle External Tables to read the file into oracle directly. At that point you can do a direct-path insert (/*+ append */) that performs the necessary transformation.  Also, if the table is nologging the you will save on redo costs, but need to take into the account that the data could be lost / need to be reloaded in the case of a media failure before the next backup.

Also, if the data is time-based, consider using partitioning and partition exchanges. You can load the data via the method above into a index-less staging table, create the necessary indexes (again possibly as NOLOGGING) which is faster than maintaining the indexes during the insert, then 'exchange' the partition into the master table.